# rosdep update problem

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm installing groovy now.
After running "rosdep update" it show error as follows:

$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d

Hit*****************/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit*****************/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit *****************/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit*****************/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit *****************/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit*****************/releases/fuerte.yaml

ERROR: error loading sources list:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I already install fuerte and using it. There was not same problem when I installed fuerte. What I have to now?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61511/rosdep-update-problem/) by [zieben](https://answers.ros.org/users/4652/zieben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-25**:
What does `rosdep --version` print?

**Comment by [Beel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4781/beel/) on 2013-04-29**:
On my Ubuntu 12.04 system, loaded and updated yesterday and today, rosdep --version gives 0.10.14.  ...a few hours later ...And now, after the repository update mentioned below, the version is 0.10.18, and running "rosdep update" does not give any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are not using the latest version of that package. Please update "rosdep" - on Ubuntu/Debian using "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-rosdep" (at least version 0.10.18).

Rosdep has recently changed and requires a newer version since than (see http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20130423.025734.7689bd35.en.html).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Beel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4781/beel/) on 2013-04-29**:
This error still occurs with the latest version of rosdep, after doing the updates and installs, a couple of hours ago. I should say, it still occurs after doing those commands to update python-rosdep.  I am booting up my Ubuntu 12.04 on my Beagleboard to see - rosdep --version shows, 0.10.14

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-04-29**:
The current version of rosdep is 0.10.18

**Comment by [Beel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4781/beel/) on 2013-04-29**:
@tfoote - see comment from ahendrix below. I will update my system tomorrow morning in hopes that it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about that; I've been busy lately and didn't think to pull the latest debs into the ARM repo to support the changes to github.

I'm running a sync now, and you should be able to get the latest rosdep within the next hour or so. Sorry for the delay.

I'm curious: which architecture are you using, armel or armhf?

P.S: if you're having problems on an ARM board, please tag your questions with "ARM" so that I get notified.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Beel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4781/beel/) on 2013-04-29**:
In my case it is a Beagleboard with Armv7. Seems to want armhf.  I am new to ARM so I will just throw out that it seems to be OMAP3, at least that is what the /proc/cpuinfo said on the Linux that was on it before I started.  I do not know what the OP (zieben) is using.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-04-29**:
Sync complete! The new version of rosdep (and other tools as well) should be available in my ARM repo now. Enjoy!

**Comment by [Beel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4781/beel/) on 2013-04-29**:
Yes, that worked.  After the repositories were updated, I did the seuence of commands to install the newset version of python-rosdep, and now there are no error messages when running "rosdep update".